# JavaScript: getting the size of an image using getComputedStyle()

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am currently experiencing a 'strange problem'... I am a beginner in JavaScript and I want to get the height of an image in order to set the size of a .

1. I get the width of the screen
2. I set the width of an image which depend on the screen size
   => I guess the computer set also the height of the image.
3. I ask for the height of the image
4. I print it

This is the code:

```
var screenWidth = (window.innerWidth);  
myImg.width = Math.floor(screenWidth/3); // That works, my image is sized well.  
var imgLarg = getComputedStyle(myImg,null).height.toLowerCase()  
console.log(imgLarg);
```

The problem is at follow: When I refresh the page by reloading the page via the web address, it works. But, when I press the refresh button, the code return '0px'.

Comment: Please provide some more context, this can't be solved with the information in the post. An important part here is when and where this code is executed.

Comment: At this step, the code is very simple, i have simplified it to have a better understanding and the problem still remain. A simple html code with `<img src="waves.jpg" alt="photo" id="imag" />`. Juste before `</html>`, there is the js script as before, with this line `var myImg = document.querySelector('#imag')` at the beginning.  In a real situation, i want the get the height of the image to set the size a <div>. I have tried with `myImg.onload = function(){}` but i experience difficulties...

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code in `document.ready` (if you use jquery) or listen for `DOMContentLoaded`. Wait for the image to load completely before getting its dimensions. Use `.load` if you use jquery or `Image.onload()`.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/
http://api.jquery.com/load/
http://developer.mozilla.org/En/XUL/Attribute/Onload

Comment: The timing really can be an issue here, but can't you just give the answer without obtruding jQuery, which is not even tagged in the post.

Comment: @Teemu i just updated my answer to include information for vanilla javascript. I have tried my best to shed some light in the right direction.

Comment: Unfortenately `DOMContentLoaded` or jQuery's `$(document).ready()` don't wait images to load...

Comment: @Teemu that is why i have mentioned `Image.onload()` or `.load()` :)

Comment: FWIW to future readers, I am using the jQuery .load() approach, but often can still find a not-yet-computed size (0px). I'm still looking for a "style computed" event.